# How to move a text on pdf?

Tags: wpf, pdf, c#-4.0

I want to create application in .NET, which will generate PDFs. This application should enable any movement of text, which an user will want set in the PDF.

I use in my project library PDFSharp. Could you suggest me how to display a preview of PDF, and how to enable move the one string within page? Do you have any ideas?

Regarding display the PDF, currently I use:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(new System.Uri(@"c:\firstpage.pdf"));
```

Is this good solution?

Comment: PDF's are meant to be treated as a read-only output format. PostScript is a turing-complete programming language. If you're generating PDFs, I'd look at moving the text on the source, and generating a new PDF with the change.

Comment: I forgot writing that I want to open PDF file, and add on it a string. Eg. We open a PDF (only with background), and we can add the title on this, and we see how the title is moved.